# TypeScript builder pattern with mapped types and const assertion

Tags: typescript, builder, typescript-generics, typescript3.0

In TypeScript I can create a function `buildOptions(options, default)`, where `options` is an array of anything and `default` is a value that must be from the array of options. I believe this can be done because of [mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types) and [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```js
const buildOptions = <T, K extends T[][number]>(
  options: Readonly<T[]>,
  defaultOption: K
) => ({
  options,
  default: options.findIndex(x => x === defaultOption),
});

// works
buildOptions(['a', 'b'] as const, 'a');

// compile error: Argument of type '4' is not assignable to parameter of type '2 | 1 | 3'.
buildOptions([1, 2, 3] as const, 4);
```

Is it possible to add this level of typing using the builder pattern? I'd like to have an interface that is used similar to the following:

```js
optionBuilder()
  .addOption(1)
  .addOption(2)
  .addOption(3)
  .setDefault(4) // compile error
  .build();
```

Or possibly:

```js
optionBuilder()
  .addOptions([1, 2, 3] as const)
  .setDefault(4) // compile error
  .build();
```

If this can't be done in TypeScript, does anyone know what language this could be done in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can :)

```js
class Builder<T> {
    addOption<V>(v: V): Builder<T | V> {
        // do your stuff

        return this as Builder<T | V>;
    }

    setDefault(v: T): this {
        // do your stuff

        return this;
    }

    build(): T[] {        
        // return list of all options ??
    }
}

function optionBuilder(): Builder<never> {
    return new Builder();
}

optionBuilder()
    .addOption(1 as const)
    .addOption('str' as const)
    .setDefault(1)  // OK
    .setDefault(12) // compile error
    .setDefault('str') // OK
    .setDefault('strstr') // compile error

    .build();
```

Note that

- all the `as const` are necessary, otherwise `1` is considered as `number` (for example);
- the `never` type given to the return type of `optionBuilder` is necessary to ensure that our builder begin with NO type at all, otherwise it will use `unknown` instead and accept everything;

Maybe there is a better solution, I hope !

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you so much. Do you happen to know if there is a proposal to define arguments as having to be const assertions, so it's not the responsibility of the interface user to know to do this? I know this would require the function to only work with literals, but I'm OK with that.

Comment: @AndrewFerk I filed [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) a while ago, which is similar to what you want.  If you look in there, it also shows how you can get the compiler to infer narrower types today with some non-intuitive syntax (aka evil wizardry).

Comment: I just noticed that I must use `setDefault` after adding all my options. This is fine, given my example, but I was trying to NOT enforce a hierarchy. It's almost as though I want the type checking to not occur until the `build` function is called. At the same time, I'd like intellisense when the options are known. Is it possible to allow `setDefault` to be called before or after `addOption` function calls?